# Serving CSS documents from Yesod

Tags: haskell, types, yesod

I'm just getting started with Yesod and trying to serve up a small CSS file from the server.

I originally wrote :

```
getMainStyleR :: Handler HTML
getMainStyleR = [cassius|
    #main
        color: 333333
        font-family: Sans
|]
```

which gives me the following type error :

```
 Couldn't match expected type `t0
                                  -> shakespeare-css-1.0.7.1:Text.Css.Css'
                with actual type `HandlerT HelloWorld IO Html'
```

I assume because CSS isn't HTML? Is this right?

If so, if I take out the type declaration for getMainStyleR (in order to see what Haskell infers) I get

```
Couldn't match expected type `HandlerT site0 IO res0'
                with actual type `t0 -> shakespeare-css-1.0.7.1:Text.Css.Css'
```

So I assume that handlers need to be given HTML, so what do I do if I want to produce CSS?

I guessed at :

```
getMainStyleR :: Handler Css
getMainStyleR = [cassius|
    #main
        color: 333333
        font-family: Sans
|]
```

But that just says :

```
Not in scope: type constructor or class `Css'
```

Is there a type for returning chunks of CSS? (It seems the sort of thing you're going to need at some point)

Update :

I tried @Michael Snoyman's suggestion below. I'm now getting this error :

```
No instance for (ToTypedContent Css)
      arising from a use of `yesodRunner'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (ToTypedContent Css)
    In the expression: yesodRunner getMainStyleR
    In the expression:
      ((Data.Text.Encoding.encodeUtf8 . Data.Text.pack) "GET", 
       yesodRunner getMainStyleR)
    In the first argument of `containers-0.5.0.0:Data.Map.Base.fromList', namely
      `[((Data.Text.Encoding.encodeUtf8 . Data.Text.pack) "GET", 
         yesodRunner getMainStyleR)]'
```

Answer (score 4):

Answering the simplest part first: you need to import the `Css` data type in order to use it. Using [Hoogle](https://www.fpcomplete.com/hoogle?q=Css&env=ghc-7.4.2-stable-13.09), you can see that it's available from the `Text.Lucius` and `Text.Cassius` modules. So you need to add `import Text.Lucius (Css)` or the like to your import statements.

The next issue is the actual type of the `cassius` quote. The best place to learn about this is in the [Yesod book's chapter on Shakespeare](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/shakespearean-templates). The important bit is that `cassius` is producing a *function*, not a plain `Css` value. The argument to the function is a URL rendering function. So to get that, you'll need to use [`getUrlRenderParams`](http://haddocks.fpcomplete.com/fp/7.4.2/20130829-168/yesod-core/Yesod-Core-Handler.html#v%3agetUrlRenderParams).

One final issue is that you need to return your result in the `Handler` monad, which requires using `return` to wrap up the pure value.

Putting that together, your handler function would look something like:

```
getMainStyleR = do
    render <- getUrlRenderParams
    return $ [cassius|...|] render
```

Comment: Thanks. That took me further, but seems to have hit a problem deeper in the framework. I've updated the main question with the new error message. Any ideas?

Comment: That's just a missing instance declaration. It's never really come up before that someone wanted to serve CSS in this way. I've [added that instance in yesod-core 1.2.11](https://github.com/yesodweb/yesod/commit/7512cc2bfc6e10985abd066c3175b0890e4073d0)

Comment: Thanks @Michael Snoyman. Sorry, haven't had a chance to get back to my Yesod explorations, but will try to this week.